# How to perform file operations faster without exceptions?

Tags: c#, winforms, file-io

I have developed an appilication to perform some back end file operations for my project.

The application will write a binary file, and peform some action in that, and which results in the creation of another file.
Then i'll read the output file to update my data base.

For example consider i'll write an `ABC.bin` file and the output file is `XYZ.bin`

All the above mentioned actions will be done in 10 milliseconds. And i'll continue the same process for a number of times for example 100 times.

Now, the problem is that i'm gettin some exceptions like file not found,access denied while running my application from the source code.

But i'm not getting the same exceptions after making the application as an executable file(.exe).

What is happening in both the cases? Why the same thing is not happening after making it as an executable file?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. But exceptions are *much* faster if you have no debugger attached.

Comment: You can't (in general) run C# code from the source code; it always generates an EXE file. Your problem is down to the difference in how you're running that EXE file (inside/outside Visual Studio). Probably due to the working directory.

Comment: @Roger Lipscombe : Yeah... i'm getting exceptions while running the exe inside the Visual Studio but its not occuring outside the IDE

Comment: Are you sure these exceptions don't happen? Or do you just not notice them?

Comment: @CodeInChaos : The same is not occuring while running the application outside the IDE

Comment: Then give us some code. You make an extraordinary claim without presenting any details. How should we help you?

Answer (score 1):

Few things you could do:

- if you are only seeing exceptions while under debugger and not when you run standalone executable, check exception settings in your Visual Studio. Go to `Debug -> Exceptions ...` and make sure that everything in `Thrown` is unchecked
- investigate if it would be faster to query if file exists using [File.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) method before starting to copy (this is of course solution only to `FileNotFoundException`)
- wrap copying loop inside a try-catch block, instead of wrapping code which is inside the loop. Like so:

  ```
  List<string> fileNames = new List<string>() { "file1.txt", "file2.txt", ... };
  int i = 0;
  try
  {
      for (i = 0; i < fileNames.Count; i++)
          // do copying here
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    // log exception
  }
  // You can decide if to return to copying rest of the files here, from i+1
  ```

This is all done to avoid entering and exiting `try` block for each file which has it's cost.

Comment: "this is of course solution only to FileNotFoundException" and of course it's only useful as an early out, it can't prevent the exception entirely. Also I'm not sure if it actually increases performance. I wouldn't be surprised if it decreases the performance on average since now the file gets opened twice.

Comment: I agree with you that you never know with performance, that's why I said he can investigate this and didn't make any claims. Anyhow, I tried it myself, and over 1000 iterations results are: File.Exists 0.0036562s, try/catch over individual File.Copy 2.3249567s. Also, File.Exists doesn't cure everything, you could still get exception afterwards of course but as you can see it's much better to check beforehand and even get false positives than to just throw around try/catch blocks.

Comment: Did you have a debugger attached? The numbers for `File.Copy` are about 10 times higher than I expected. And in many scenarios most files you check exist. Edit: Just tested. `File.Copy` takes only around 200us for me, i.e. it's about 10 times as fast as what you measured.

Comment: Yes, I was in debug mode. So in standalone it's still 10x faster than to go for individual try/catch. I'd never sit down to try this if there weren't for you :)

Comment: Interestingly it doesn't seem to be the exception itself that costs this much time. Must be something else `File.Copy` does. I can throw and catch 40k exceptions per second, but only 5k failed `File.Copy`s.